# Table td overflow scrolling with vertical align middle

Tags: html, css

I have added a `table` inside a `table` `td`. The inside `table` `td` needs to scroll when its contain more text, so I just added a span into it and applied CSS properties for limit the `height` with `overflow-y: auto`

The problem is: **How can I align text vertically middle in inside table td?**

or Need to apply `vertical-align: middle;` for **"Sub Text"**

Here is the code:

```css
td {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.tbl-small {
  width: 100%;
}

.tbl-small td {
  height: 40px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.tbl-small td span {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table width="400px;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="25%">Main text</td>
      <td width="25%">
        <table class="tbl-small"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Sub text</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Sub text</span></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td width="25%">
        <table class="tbl-small"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Sub text</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Sub text</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Sub text</span></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td width="25%">Main text</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/vishnuprasadps/5684aupk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `max-height` instead of `height`

```
.tbl-small td span {
  max-height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```css
td {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.tbl-small {
  width: 100%;
}

.tbl-small td {
  height: 40px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.tbl-small td span {
  max-height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table width="400px;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="25%">Main text</td>
      <td width="25%">
        <table class="tbl-small"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Sub text</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Sub text</span></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td width="25%">
        <table class="tbl-small"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Sub text</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Sub text</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Sub text</span></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td width="25%">Main text</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Great ! I never thought about max-height for span.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your `span` inside `td`:

```
td span{
display:flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center // this only for horizontal align
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `line-height` to td and also inherit `line-height:inherit` where you have scroll.

```css
td {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.tbl-small {
  width: 100%;
}

.tbl-small td {
  height: 40px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.tbl-small td span {
  max-height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table width="400px;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="25%">Main text</td>
      <td width="25%">
        <table class="tbl-small"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td><span class="scroll">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Sub text</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Sub text</span></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td width="25%">
        <table class="tbl-small"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Sub text</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Sub text</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Sub text</span></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td width="25%">Main text</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: But sometimes all other td may have more text.

Comment: in that case we have to use max-height instead of just height. i have update the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

use line-height property to make it vertically center
add this css in your code

```
.tbl-small td {
  height: 40px;
  overflow: auto;
  line-height:40px;
}
```